# How to add S3 storage to Gitlab Runner using Cluster Management Project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am currently using Gitlab, its pipelines, and its runners in my Rancher k8s environment.  I want to setup some S3 storage so I can use caching in my Runners.

I have been modifying my version of https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/project-templates/cluster-management/-/blob/master/applications/gitlab-runner/values.yaml.gotmpl by adding the following to the file.

```yaml
  config: 
    cache:    
      Type: "s3"
      Shared: true
      Path: runner
      S3:
        ServerAddress: server.home.com
        AccessKey: testUser1
        SecretKey: testpassword
        BucketName: test-bucket-1
        Insecure: true
```

When this runs it fails

The error I get is a "failed to render chart: exit status 1"

What is the correct way to add the S3 bucket to this runner using the Cluster Management Project?

Answer (score 0):

on my side something like this works

```
runners:
  cache:
    secretName: superk8ssecret
  config: |
    [[runners]]
      [runners.cache]
       Type = "s3"
       Path = "path_on_s3"
       Shared = true
       [runners.cache.s3]
         ServerAddress = "s3_server_name"
         BucketName = "bucket_name"
         BucketLocation = "eu-central-1"
         Insecure = false
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).